# GSON Convert Unicode Hexadecimal to UTF 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

We have a json file which contains the following Unicode Hexadecimal values.

```
[{
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "\\0x3059\\0x3079\\0x3066\\0x306E Test \\0x30DB\\0x30B9\\0x30C8\\0x7528\\0x306E\\0x30C7\\0x30D5\\0x30A9\\0x30EB\\0x30C8 \\0x30DB\\0x30B9\\0x30C8 \\0x30B0\\0x30EB\\0x30FC\\0x30D7\\0x3002"
  }
]
```

Do we have any way to convert these Unicode Hexadecimal values to UTF-8 while reading using GSON library.

e.g:

gson.fromJson(reader, JsonElement.class);

Comment: The design of these JSON strings seems to be broken because of non-trivial `\\0x`. Is it possible to modify the JSON so that all `\\0x` could be replaced with `\u` (assuming your server side)? Then it would perfectly be decoded to `[{"name":"Test","description":"すべての Test ホスト用のデフォルト ホスト グループ。"}]`.

Comment: unfortunately we are at the client side. I can try if we can replace all \\0x with \u. Meanwhile can you let me whats your logic for decode?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, your strings are UTF-16-like, not UTF-8, due to 16-bit codes prefixed by `\\0x` (I still don't get that UTF-8 and Unicode magic.) One of possible solutions might be buffering entire input into a string buffer, doing string replace from `\\0x` to `\u` and then let Gson consume the new string. Not sure if it's a good way because string replace is totally context free and may break such strings. Additionally, string replace does not care of JSON format grammar at all. Another solution is extending `JsonReader` so that Gson could decode such strings itself not breaking JSON grammar.

For example:

```java
public final class DecodingJsonReader
        extends JsonReader {

    private final Function<? super CharSequence, String> nameDecoder;
    private final Function<? super CharSequence, String> stringDecoder;

    private DecodingJsonReader(@WillClose final Reader in, final Function<? super CharSequence, String> nameDecoder,
            final Function<? super CharSequence, String> stringDecoder) {
        super(in);
        this.nameDecoder = nameDecoder;
        this.stringDecoder = stringDecoder;
    }

    public static JsonReader create(@WillClose final Reader in, final Function<? super CharSequence, String> nameDecoder,
            final Function<? super CharSequence, String> stringDecoder) {
        return new DecodingJsonReader(in, nameDecoder, stringDecoder);
    }

    @Override
    public String nextName()
            throws IOException {
        return nameDecoder.apply(super.nextName());
    }

    @Override
    public String nextString()
            throws IOException {
        return stringDecoder.apply(super.nextString());
    }

}
```

The following decoder fails for `\0x`-prefixed numbers whose next four characters are not hex-digits. Index bounds checking is delegated to objects in use. It is a big field for improvements of course. Its `StringBuilder` is reused (not sure but this may save some performance?).

```java
final class ZeroExDecoder {

    private final StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    private ZeroExDecoder(final StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        this.stringBuilder = stringBuilder;
    }

    static ZeroExDecoder create(final StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
        return new ZeroExDecoder(stringBuilder);
    }

    String decode(final CharSequence cs) {
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        final int length = cs.length();
        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            final char p0 = cs.charAt(i);
            if ( p0 != '\\' ) {
                stringBuilder.append(p0);
                continue;
            }
            final char p1 = cs.charAt(++i);
            if ( p1 != '0' ) {
                stringBuilder.append(p1);
                continue;
            }
            final char p2 = cs.charAt(++i);
            if ( p2 != 'x' ) {
                stringBuilder.append(p2);
                continue;
            }
            final int d3 = Character.digit(cs.charAt(++i), 16) << 12;
            final int d2 = Character.digit(cs.charAt(++i), 16) << 8;
            final int d1 = Character.digit(cs.charAt(++i), 16) << 4;
            final int d0 = Character.digit(cs.charAt(++i), 16);
            stringBuilder.append((char) (d3 | d2 | d1 | d0));
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Test:

```java
public final class DecodingJsonReaderTest {

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .disableInnerClassSerialization()
            .create();

    // immutable, thread-safe, and can be shared globally
    private static final Function<CharSequence, String> nameDecoder = CharSequence::toString;

    @Test
    public void testCreate()
            throws IOException {
        // mutable, not thread-safe, should not be shared (but can be wisely reused)
        final Function<? super CharSequence, String> stringDecoder = ZeroExDecoder.create(new StringBuilder(128))::decode;
        final StringReader reader = new StringReader("[{\"name\":\"Test\",\"description\":\"\\\\0x3059\\\\0x3079\\\\0x3066\\\\0x306E Test \\\\0x30DB\\\\0x30B9\\\\0x30C8\\\\0x7528\\\\0x306E\\\\0x30C7\\\\0x30D5\\\\0x30A9\\\\0x30EB\\\\0x30C8 \\\\0x30DB\\\\0x30B9\\\\0x30C8 \\\\0x30B0\\\\0x30EB\\\\0x30FC\\\\0x30D7\\\\0x3002\"}]\n");
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = DecodingJsonReader.create(reader, nameDecoder, stringDecoder) ) {
            final String description = gson.<JsonElement>fromJson(jsonReader, JsonElement.class)
                    .getAsJsonArray()
                    .get(0)
                    .getAsJsonObject()
                    .getAsJsonPrimitive("description")
                    .getAsString();
            Assertions.assertEquals("すべての Test ホスト用のデフォルト ホスト グループ。", description);
        }
    }

}
```

The code above should be well-tested first and fixed if necessary before real use.

Answer (score -1):

1. Read your JSON file by using InputStreamReader with encoding like UTF-8

```java
InputStream inputStream = new InputStream(new File("input.text"));
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

2. converting data from InputStreamReader to Object(any type what you want)

```java
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type encodedData = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, Type.class);
```

reference :

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)
2. https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.reflect.Type-

Comment: As your comment, replace from `\\0x` to `\u` by using replace or replaceAll after read JSON file.